# Powershell is not returning the right values for csv

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have a small script to grad PC battery power and write to a text file (I tried export-csv) every 60 seconds.  However, the script just keeps writing the same value to the file and does not change or increment is properly.

```
$csvfile = "c:\Users\PC-battery.csv"
$Battstatus = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Battery).estimatedchargeremaining 
while ($true) 
    {
        "$Battstatus" | Add-Content $csvfile   
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
```

Comment: you are only reading the source ONCE. i don't think that result will be a live WMI object, so you are always going to see the same result. ///// try moving the query into the `while` loop ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 3):

The issue you have is that the value of `$Battstatus` is never updated after the first time you set it. You're asking the system for the battery status once and then entering an infinite loop where you just refer back to that one value.

Instead, you'll want to retrieve the value *inside* the loop, like so:

```
$csvfile = "c:\Users\PC-battery.csv"
while ($true) 
    {
        $Battstatus = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Battery).estimatedchargeremaining 
        $Battstatus | Add-Content $csvfile   
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
```

I also took the quotes off your variable reference as I don't think they were necessary (unless I'm misunderstanding the value of the variable, you can put them back on if you need them).

Also of note: `Add-Content` just appends to a file, it isn't CSV aware. You can take advantage of PowerShell's use of objects and put all the battery info into a proper CSV like this:

```
$csvfile = "c:\Users\PC-battery.csv"
while ($true) 
    {
        $Battstatus = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Battery
        $Battstatus | Export-Csv $csvfile -NoTypeInformation -Append   
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
```

(untested, might have some quirks)